# ¿Cómo importar Excel al SQL server en mas de una tabla al tiempo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, visual-studio-2015

Buen día compañeros,

tengo el siguiente codigo .CS que importa un archivo excel a una tabla en la base de datos, funciona excelente, pero me surge la duda de como ingreso un excel a 2 o más tablas?

```
using System;.....

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if you have Excel 2007 uncomment this line of code
        //  string excelConnectionString =string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0",path);


        string ExcelContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string Excel2010ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            //Check the Content Type of the file
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == ExcelContentType || FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == Excel2010ContentType)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Save file path
                    string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), FileUpload1.FileName);
                    //Save File as Temp then you can delete it if you want
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
                    //string path = @"C:\Users\Johnney\Desktop\ExcelData.xls";
                    //For Office Excel 2010  please take a look to the followng link  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/0f03c2de-3ee2-475f-b6a2-f4efb97de302/#ae1e6748-297d-4c6e-8f1e-8108f438e62e
                    string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);

                    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                    using (OleDbConnection connection =
                                 new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                                ("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

                        connection.Open();

                        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            // SQL Server Connection String
                            string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=Pruebas_Insert; User ID=usuario;Password=admin*****;";

                            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                                       new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "PruebasExcel";
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

                                LabelMsgCorrect.Text = "<strong>Bien!</strong> La base seleccionada se ha cargado correctamente! <span aria-hidden='true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-saved'>&nbsp;</span>";

                                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);

                                Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "15; url=Default.aspx");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
                    LabelMsgError.Text = ex.Message;
                    Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "7; url=Default.aspx");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es subir el contenido de una hoja de excel en dos tablas diferentes de sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conocer dinamicamente cuentas tablas\sheet(solapas) tiene el excel podrias usar el schema desde ado.net, el cual te permite descubrir la estructura

[Read schema information from Excel worksheets with ADO.NET](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/Schema.aspx)

en el ejemplo veras como hace uso del `GetOleDbSchemaTable()` con esto obtienes los nombres que usaras en un loop y armar dinamicamente el select

Comment: pero con eso obtengo el schema del Excel pero no el como se insertan en la base de datos, no comprendo bien como es, en teoría lo que necesito es cargar el archivo de excel a una vista SQL, algo asi.